# How to format family tree from array

Tags: php, css, arrays

I'm trying to create a pedigree and I've got the function to both build and to display the data, I'm just not sure how to format it correctly on output.

I'm trying to work with this css/html http://jsfiddle.net/bZGFA/32/

My array output of the tree information looks like this:

```
Array(
 [id] => IJ6wF
 [mother] => Array (
     [id] => BzOqN
     [mother] => Array (
         [id] => 1G3Pl
         [mother] => 
         [father] =>
     )
     [father] => Array (
         [id] => xWDlH
         [mother] => 
         [father] =>
     )
 )
 [father] => Array (
     [id] => Rstov
     [mother] =>
     [father] =>
 )
)
```

I'm using a recursive function to build the array.  I'm using the following function I found on stackoverflow to display the array.

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '--');
            } else {
                //  Output
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    echo "$level $indent $value \n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm lost on how I can configure the function to build the table.  Any help would be amazing.  Thanks!

Comment: So your function is already `echo`ing the data correctly? You just need to modify the `echo` to include the relevant HTML segments, which you can then style with CSS.

Comment: That's the part I need help with - how to define which part of the HTML I need to throw at any given level.  Does that make sense?  :)

Comment: Seems like lists and nested lists. I would assume a brute-force method would be to either echo out the appropriate HTML or to build up a string containing the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
printTree($array) {
    $out = "<li>" . "<a href='#'>". $array["id"] . "</a>";

    if (array_key_exists("mother", $array) || array_key_exists("father", $array)) {

        $out .= "<ul>";

        if (array_key_exists("mother", $array)) {
            $out .= printTree($array["mother"]);
        }

        if (array_key_exists("father", $array)) {
            $out .= printTree($array["father"]);
        }

        $out .= "</ul>";
    }

    $out .= "</li>";

    return $out;
}
```

While in the html use:

```
<ul class="tree desc3">
    <?php echo printTree($array); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Would you be willing to help me figure out how to have it format for a table format?  I don't know how to calculate the rowspan part of it?

http://jsfiddle.net/M2r7D/1/